# R match arrays by noncomformable margin

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, margins

Working with two arrays in R.

```
array1[x,y]
array2[x,y,t]
```

and I would like to compute an array3[x,y] that holds the t index that defines minimum difference between array2 and array1. These arrays were read in from netcdf files. It would be good to avoid a loop. Any help/insight is greatly appreciated.

A loop example might be similar to:

```
for i in 1:nx {
  for j in 1:ny {
     for k in 1:nt {
        mindiff[i,j,k] = array1[i,j]-array2[i,j,k]
     }
    #the minimum values over the k dimension
    result[i,j] = sapply(mindiff, 3, min)
  }
}
```

Would like result[i,j] to be the index values of k rather than the actual min values?

Comment: Please provide [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: `...like to compute an array3[x,y] that holds the t index...` sounds a little confusing to me. And you ask for array3[two params], and the continue about mindiff[3 params] and result[2 params]. Which is which?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the minimum difference for each:

```
library("plyr")
library("matrixStats")
result <- t(laply(1:(dim(array1)[2]), function(j) rowMins(array1[, j, ] - array2[, j])))
```

If you wanted the smallest absolute difference you'd need to use `abs`.

For the index of each, you'd need to nest a further laply and use which.min:

```
library("plyr")
result <- laply(1:nrow(array2),
  function(i) laply(1:ncol(array2),
  function(j) which.min(abs(array1[i, j, ] - array2[i, j]))
))
```

Comment: Thanks, Nick for the help.

Comment: @Matt did the latter of those address your problem? If the arrays are large, it's worth considering using the `.parallel` option of the outer `laply` especially if you're on a machine that supports `registerDoMC` (i.e. not Windows).

Comment: @nick_k thanks again, I got a partial solution working. One follow up question is: with the indices in result[i,j], which represent the values of t, how can I use those back in say array1[i,j,t] and collapse the t dimension?

Comment: @Matt `fin <- matrix(array1[cbind(c(row(result)), c(col(result)), c(result))], nrow = nrow(result))`